# Managing/saving a (nested?) 2d data array with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have the following arrays:

```
var a = ["Sample A", "Sample B"];
var b = ["X", "Y", "Z"];
```

Now let's say I have a button that, when clicked, generates the header of a 2D table, like this:

<kbd>Sample A</kbd><kbd>Sample B</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

...and another button that adds a new row to the table:

<kbd>Sample A</kbd><kbd>Sample B</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

How would I do the following things:

- save/restore data from/to the table
- manage insertions/deletions from any of the arrays that form the header

Notes:

- the elements of the arrays that form the header can be deleted in any order, but new elements can be appended at the end.
- ... however, I expect specs to change slightly so that the elements in those arrays can change their position.

EDIT: As suggested by users, I'm adding a plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FMIgwqKKDbZOCjNTXrrh?p=preview

I know this is flawed and wrong because it's tracking the data by it's index (which is error prone).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Where's your code? Question it too much broad.

Comment: You're asking to do quite a bit. Is it do-able? Yes absolutely. But with out knowing your app/data/html structure it is insane to try and answer. You should take a stab at trying to do this and post the code so we have something to work off of to help you. All the things you are describing are absolutely do-able. Give it a shot.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Whaat I'm asking depends directly on the data structure, which I don't know (if I knew I wouldn't be asking). Surely I can place in there an array of arrays, but how would I manage the ordering/deletion/insertion problem? I could do a simple plunkr, but it would be nearly pointless.

Comment: You should at least attempt it and post it, even if it's not right. You are asking how to do all these things which is basically saying build this for me off of nothing. You have to give stack something to work with. If you know how to build this but don't know how to off an unknown data structure, how is someone else suppose to know?

Comment: @ajmajmajma Added plunkr example

Comment: @tymeJV Added plunkr exaple (check edit)